# Incompatible types in DELPHI and Opencv

Tags: delphi, opencv, image-processing, pascal, imagej

I am trying to find contour into a picture. I implement as follows but i get

> Incompatible types: 'ocv.core.types_c.pCvMemStorage' and 'UWaterShedSegment.pCvMemStorage' error.

```
 type
      pCvMemStorage = ^TCvMemStorage;
      pCvSeq = ^TCvSeq;
    .
    .
    .
    var
      contours :  pCvMemStorage;
      first_contour :   pCvSeq;
    .
    .
    .
    cvFindContours(DistImgEq, contours, first_contour, SizeOf(TCvContour) ,CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,cvPoint(0,0));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've redeclared the type `pCvMemStorage` in your own unit and this is hiding the declared type in the `ocv.core.types_c` unit that is required by the method signature of `cvFindContours`.

Remove the type declaration from your unit and, if it is not already there, add the `ocv.core.types_c` unit to your `uses` clause.

Comment: @KaanAykutKABAKÇI Then You are supposed to accept the answer of J.

Comment: @KaanAykutKABAKÇI You need to tick "V" against the answer.